# Como puedo actualizar el total por los datos que se ingresan

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create trigger t2 before insert on Pedido
for each row
begin
   if new.num_ped>0 then
      set @i=@i+1;
      update pedido inner join platillo as pl on new.idplatillo=pl.idplatillo set total= pl.precio * new.cantidad where num_ped=@i;
    end if;
end//
```

Ya intenté de muchas maneras y no me sale error pero no cambia el total.
Creí que era porque no leía ningún `id`, así que le puse un incremento, pero tampoco. Incluso puse un numero fijo, y tampoco.

Comment: Yo no entiendo para nada el sentido de esa instruccion.. que estas tratando de actualizar?

Answer (score 0):

Estás cometiendo, primero, un fallo de concepto. En un trigger *before insert*, qué significa **antes de insertar**, el registro no existe en la base de datos, por tanto, no tiene sentido lanzar un `update` a la tabla, para actualizar un registro que aún no está allí.

Lo que tienes en el trigger, es el pseudo-registro `new`, que tiene la misma estructura de la tabla. Puedes *manipular* los datos que van a quedar guardados en la tabla a través de este registro, asignando directamente valores a sus campos.

Por ejemplo, para asignar un valor constante:

```
create trigger t2 before insert on Pedido
for each row
begin
  set new.total = 1000;
end;
```

Si quieres realizar el cálculo tomando en cuenta valores de otra tabla, el `select/into` es la vía, en algo como:

```
create trigger t2 before insert on Pedido
for each row
begin
  select platillo.precio * new.cantidad
    into new.total
    from platillo
   where platillo.idplatillo = new.idplatillo;
end;
```